# Variable naming in for loops

Tags: for-loop, python-2.7

I'm writing a function that supposed to work with lists of lists, and if I use this example:

```
def mode(year):
    monthAmount = len(year)

    for month in year:
        (month)Index = len(month)
```

What I want this to do is, say *year* is [January, February, March], the results should be something like this: JanuaryIndex = *, FebruaryIndex = *, MarchIndex = *, and so on; with a number of different months. Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am not entirely sure what you are looking for here.

To get an index into a sequence you are looping over *together with the actual value*, use the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index, month in enumerate(year):
    print index, month
```

You really do not want to dynamically set global variables. Use a dictionary instead:

```
monthindices = {}

for month in year:
    monthindices[month] = len(month)
```

You *can* create global variables dynamically, by accessing the [`globals()` mapping](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals), but doing this is *generally a bad idea*. You'd do it like this if you are stubborn:

```
gl = globals()
for month in year:
    gl['{}Index'.format(month)] = len(month)
```